# Html sidebar that's sticky and limited to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an HTML sidebar that is limited to divs size (not fullscreen like regular sidebars) and that is also sticky so that when the divs height exceeds the screen's height the sidebar sticks to the screen and does not scroll.

So far, I made the first part. The sidebar is limited to the height of the div it is contained in.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Top text</h2>
<div class="filtering">

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <div id="sticky">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" class="close" id="closefilter"></a>
    <div id="filterheader">Filter</div>
    <div id="filtercontent">
      <div id="subfilterheader">Platforms</div>
      <ul style="list-style: none;" id="filterlist">
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filtersteam" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('steam')"/>Steam</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filterepic" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('epic')"/>Epic</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filterorigin" type="checkbox" rel="origin" onchange="changeFilter('origin')"/>Origin</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filtergog" type="checkbox" rel="gog" onchange="changeFilter('gog')"/>GOG</label>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
</div>
<h1>Bottom text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav #filterheader {
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}

p{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.filtering{
  position: relative;
}


#subfilterheader{
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#filterlist{
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
}

#sticky{
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 30px;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

JS - opening and closing of the sidebar

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

JS fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4a31mgw0/

My goal is to combine it with something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yn5rv0ke/ 
**Is there a way to make the sidebar both limited to div and sticky?**

Comment: Do you still want the sidebar to close and open (unlike the fiddle you provided as your goal)?

Comment: Yes I would like to keep that functionality. That second fiddle was to show the sticky part.

Comment: I'm not sure if it possible to combine them just in css, you'd have to add a javascript calculation that looks at the size and toggles different behavior depending on that. 

Other than that I would make the #sticky position absolute, and the container position relative. Look at how relative + absolute behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to know that for a div to be sticky, it has to have a height defined. If I understood correctly what you want to do, the problem in your previous code is that you put the sticky div inside the sidebar, and then assigned the height to the sidebar.

Also, it is easier to work with separate divs, i.e. your sidebar div and your content div.

In this solution, I added the `display: flex` to the main div (`.filtering`) and wrapped your text content in another div (`.main-content`). Now your sidebar is sticky only inside the main div. However you also have to know since you put the button to open and close the div near the text content, I considered you didn't want it to be sticky.

Here is the solution : (and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apregyuf/1/))

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 250px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav #filterheader {
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}

p{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.filtering{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main-content {
  flex: 1;
}

#subfilterheader{
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#filterlist{
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Top text</h2>
    <div class="filtering">

      <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" class="close" id="closefilter"></a>
        <div id="filterheader">Filter</div>
        <div id="filtercontent">
          <div id="subfilterheader">Platforms</div>
          <ul style="list-style: none;" id="filterlist">
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input id="filtersteam" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('steam')" />Steam</label>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input id="filterepic" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('epic')" />Epic</label>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input id="filterorigin" type="checkbox" rel="origin" onchange="changeFilter('origin')" />Origin</label>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input id="filtergog" type="checkbox" rel="gog" onchange="changeFilter('gog')" />GOG</label>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
      <div class="main-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Bottom text</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a4puk90d/)

Basically, you need `position: fixed` for your  `#mySidenav` element. But since that rule takes the element out of the document flow and it cannot have dynamic height anymore, I have added a bit `js` code to modify its style according to its container (I have added the id `#container` at the parent element with class `filtering`). The CSS and JS changes are applied at  `#mySidenav` element and not the `.sticky` one, in order to have the desired outcome.

P.S. The animation looks a bit funny when the menu opens for the first time, in that case, you can move the `js` commands that are modifying the style at an earlier stage.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`.

https://jsfiddle.net/vhgj29yk/

Answer (score 0):

Your just need to change the structure a lil bit and some css and js

```js
  function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("openBtn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("content-wrapper").style.paddingLeft = "270px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("content-wrapper").style.paddingLeft = "15px";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("openBtn").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
span#openBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
}
div#content-wrapper {
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}
.sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}
.sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background: #ccc
}
.sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background: #888
}
.sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #eee
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav #filterheader {
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}

p{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.filtering {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


#subfilterheader{
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#filterlist{
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
}

#sticky{
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 30px;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="filtering">

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <div id="sticky">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" class="close" id="closefilter"></a>
    <div id="filterheader">Filter</div>
    <div id="filtercontent">
      <div id="subfilterheader">Platforms</div>
      <ul style="list-style: none;" id="filterlist">
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filtersteam" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('steam')"/>Steam</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filterepic" type="checkbox" onchange="changeFilter('epic')"/>Epic</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filterorigin" type="checkbox" rel="origin" onchange="changeFilter('origin')"/>Origin</label>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="filtergog" type="checkbox" rel="gog" onchange="changeFilter('gog')"/>GOG</label>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Top Text</h1>
    </div>
  <span id="openBtn" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Nullam eget felis eget </p>
  
  <div class="footer"><h1>Bottom text</h1></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace You Javascript Code ... By-

```
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.overflow = "hidden";
document.getElementById("sticky").style.overflow = "hidden";
document.getElementById("sticky").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("sticky").style.background = "#111";
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("sticky").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("sticky").style.width = "0";
}
var s = document.querySelector('#sticky');
document.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
if(window.scrollY > s.offsetHeight){
    s.style.position="fixed";
}
else s.style.position="static"

});
```